# Select All Cells in Active Worksheet using ComOject Excel.Application in Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, comobject

Very new to Powershell.

**Situation:**

My script below is meant to do the following:

> 1. Open New Workbook
> 2. Put "This is A1" in the cell 'A1'
> 3. Select all cells in the Active Worksheet
> 4. Set the selection to TEXT data format

Here is my Script for Powershell:

> ```
> $excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
> $excel.visible = $true
> $book = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
> $book.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "This is A1"
> $worksheet = $book.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
> $colcount = $worksheet.columns.count
> $copyrange = $worksheet.range("1:$colcount").numberformat = "@"
> ```

**Issue:**

I don't know how to write ***Select All*** in the command because when I run my script, it only makes `'A1 & B1'` *TEXT* cells and everything else is left as *GENERAL* format. I would like to make the Range Dynamic.

This is my script in VBA:

> ```
> Sub TEXT_FORMAT()
>
>     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "This is A1"
>     Cells.Select
>     Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
>
> End Sub
> ```

The Script I tried to follow:

[How to select all in excel using Powershell](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2025786-how-to-select-all-in-excel-using-powershell)

Can anyone please help me out with how I can make this more dynamic with my SELECT ALL statement?

Much appreciated.

Comment: `$worksheet.cells.numberformat = "@"` or `$worksheet.usedrange.numberformat = "@"` without the `$copyrange = `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, it worked for me. You can apply the number formatting by either selecting **ALL rows** (or) **ALL columns**

```
$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $true
$book = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$worksheet = $book.ActiveSheet
$worksheet.Range("A1").Value2 = "This is A1" # Use the property 'Value2'
$worksheet.Rows.NumberFormat = "@"
# $worksheet.Columns.NumberFormat = "@" # this also sets number format of all cells to 'Text'
```